# How to export variable using ant script on linux

Tags: linux, ant

i want to export variable from ant script, but i am doing something wrong cause I get error:

> sh: 0: Can't open export DISPLAY=:10

There is fragment of my script

```
<target name="xvfb_start">
    <echo>Starting xvfb</echo>
    <exec executable="sh">
            <arg value="export DISPLAY=:10"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `sh` expects the first argument to be a command to execute. `export DISPLAY=:10` is no valid command (and since you pass this to `sh` as a single argument, it takes everything to be part of the script name to start, even the spaces and colon).

To make `sh` evaluate the arguments, try `sh -c`. That will give you a shell which has the variable `DISPLAY` defined. Since no further commands are on the command line, the shell will terminate and your variable will be lost with it.

Solutions:

1. String all commands together
2. Execute a script instead

For #1:

```
<exec executable="sh">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="export DISPLAY=:10 ; xvfb"/>
</exec>
```

For #2, put all the commands into a normal shell script and have `sh` execute that.

Answer (score 1):

An approach I've found helpful is to export the variable in the same command as running ant.

For example (from your shell):

```
export DISPLAY=:10 ; ant your-target-name
```

It's also the case that any variables exported in your `~/.bashrc` (if you have one) will be available to processes that ant runs.  I have my `export DISPLAY` in there on my project.  (If you're testing this, don't forget to call `reset` to get your terminal to pick up the changes to `.bashrc`).